# Applications Gelfand-Naimark-Segal Theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

I'm reading the book An Introduction to Operator Algebras (By Kehe Zhu). but do not know how to do the following exercise:

Let $A$ be the commutative C*-algebra $C(\partial D)$. For any $z\in \partial D$ let $\varphi_z$ be the point-evaluation on $z$. Show that $H_{\varphi_z}$ is one-dimensional. Show that there exists a countable subset $S'$ of $S(A)$ such that $$\Phi:A\rightarrow B\left(\bigoplus_{\varphi\in S'} H_\varphi\right)$$

as constructed in the proof of theorem 14.4 (Gelfand-Naimark-Segal Theorem) is a C*-isomorphism.

Comment: It is imposible to answer this question as stated without having the book at hand, since you did not even explain the notation. You might increase your chances of getting a useful answer (and of turning this into something usefulmfor other people) if you try to make it more self-contained.

Comment: Hi Mariano, for something below the tag "C$^*$-algebras", I wouldn't expect that notation to be explained: it is completely standard (possibly with the exception of $\partial D$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do GNS, you take $C(\partial D)$ as  your pre-Hilbert space, with the pre-inner product
$$
\langle f,g\rangle=f(z)\overline{g(z)}.
$$
Then you need to quotient by $$J_z=\{f:\ \varphi_z(f^*f)=0\}
=\{f:\ |f(z)|^2=0\}=\{f: \ f(z)=0\}.
$$
So we need to see that the quotient $C(\partial D)/J_z$ is one-dimensional. Now, $f-g\in J_z$ if and only if $g(z)=f(z)$, so the class of $f$ is determined by the value $f(z)$. That is, 
$$
C(\partial D)/J_z=\mathbb C+J_z,
$$
and it is one-dimensional. Then its closure $H_{\varphi_z}$ will also be one-dimensional.

For the second part I will assume that $\partial D$ is the unit circle (if that's the case, $\mathbb T$ is a much more common notation). Let $S\subset\partial D$ be a dense subset. For each $s\in S$, consider the state $\varphi_s(f)=f(s)$. If we now consider the map $\Phi$
\begin{align}
C(\partial D)&\longrightarrow B\left(\bigoplus_{s\in S}\mathbb C\right)=B\left(\bigoplus_{s\in S}H_{\varphi_s}\right)\\
f&\longmapsto \ \ \ \ \ M_f
\end{align}
where $M_f[g_s]_{s\in S}=[f(s)g_s]_{s\in S}$. 
This is clearly a $*$-homomorphism, and if $M_f=0$, then $f(s)=0$ for all $s\in S$ (by taking $g$ to be $1$ at $s$ and zero elsewhere), and so  $f=0$ by continuity; thus $\Phi$ is a monomorphism. This map is not necessarily onto, but I think the book here is using "C$^*$-isomorphism" as a name for a $*$-monomorphism.

The set $S'$ is of course the set $S'=\{\varphi_s:\ s\in S\}$.

Comment: Ok, But the map $\Phi$ is on $B\left(\bigoplus_{\varphi\in S′} H_{\varphi_s}\right)$, that is, Bounded Linear Operators on a Hilbert Space.

Comment: My bad. I think it is fine now.